# Spark MLLib Alternative to sklearn's TFIDF Vectorizer

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I am looking for an alternative to sklearn's `TfIdfVectorizer` in Spark's MLLib

As per [Spark MLLib's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf),

*TF: Both `HashingTF` and `CountVectorizer` can be used to generate the term frequency vectors.*

My question is, if I use MLLib's `CountVectorizer` for TF *(since Spark's MLLib doesn't seem to have a `TfIdfVectorizer`)*, and use MLLib's `IDF` on top of that, would it be equivalent to sklearn's `TfIdfVectorizer`?

Or do I need to use something like a `TfIdfTransformer` over MLLib's `CountVectorizer` to achieve the same output as sklearn's `TfIdfVectorizer`? (which seems fishy to me)

**NOTE : I am not talking about the data structure of the result but rather the equivalence of the algorithm implementations.**

The limitation is that I cannot use `HashingTF` to keep the implementation equivalent to `TfIdfVectorizer` in `sklearn`